# Laravel 5 AJAX submit internal server error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, internal-server-error

I have scoured the web for many hours trying to solve this issue.  I am pretty new to AJAX.  So I have been getting a internal server 500 error in the console when trying to submit my data to the controller.  I am thinking it is a CSRF mismatch, but I have tried everything I can think of that would solve that.  I used the meta tag method in my layout.blade.php for AJAX CSRF submission.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My comment code looks like this.  I'm passing `$p->id` to the route, which passes to the controller.

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {!! Form::model($p, ['route' => ['new_comment.post', $p->id]]) !!}
        <div class = "comment submit">
            <textarea id = "comment_content" placeholder = "Your comment goes here!" name = "comment_content" class = "content_display comment"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class = "action">
            <li><a class = "comment_button new" href = "#"><i class = "fa fa-check"></i></a></li>
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@else
    <p><a href = "/login">Log in to post a comment</a></p>
@endif
```

My AJAX:

```
<script>
$('.comment_button.new').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var comment_content = $('#comment_content').val();
    var data = 'comment_content'+comment_content;
    var url =  window.location.pathname;

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : data,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(){ 

        }
    });
    return false;
});

</script>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/home/view/{id}', ['as' => 'new_comment.post', 'before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'ViewPost@new_comment']);
```

My controller:

```
class ViewPost extends Controller
{

public function show($id)
{
    $posts = Posts::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
    $comments = Comments::where('post_id', '=', $id)->get();
    return view('view')->with('posts', $posts)->with('comments', $comments);
}

public function new_comment(Request $request, $id)
{
    $comment_postID = $id;
    $comment_data = $request->input('comment_content');

    if($request->ajax()) {
        $com = new Comment;
        $com->post_id = $comment_postID;
        $com->comment_content = $comment_data;
        $com->save();
    }
}


}
```

EDIT

Here is a stack trace of the issue http://pastebin.com/tNcN5bLP

SOLVED

My 'Comments' model was being invoked using 'Comment'.  I fixed it by adding an s to the end.  Woops!

Also,

I was posting the data improperly using AJAX, so my controller wasn't able to read the input.  This fragment from my AJAX

```
var data = 'comment_content'+comment_content;
data : data,
```

Should have been

```
data : {comment_content:comment_content},
```

Thanks!

Comment: think more about   `var url =  window.location.pathname;` , write url something like this and test  `url: window.location.pathname; + '/home/view/' + commentId`

Comment: @Pedrammarandi '/home/view/{{ $p->id }}' puts up the same url as window.location.pathname

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your master template(the one you always extend for every new page):

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                            }
                        });
        });
    </script>
```

Make sure it's a blade template so it properly handles the braces.

Also, try enabling dubug mode and inspect the response to make sure it's not something else entirely, it'll be easier to help if you update your answer with the full stack trace of the problem.

Comment: I tried your code instead and it didn't fix anything.  Here is my stack trace.

http://pastebin.com/tNcN5bLP

Comment: now I'm missing the actual exception (the error on top)

Comment: Wow sorry about that.  Looks like it's a BadMethodCallException.  This narrows it down a lot.  http://pastebin.com/Dk5G6CqW

Comment: Figured it out.  The 'Comments' model was being invoked as 'Comment'.  Missed an s.  Woops.  Now to figure out the integrity constraint violation of 'comment_content' being null.  http://pastebin.com/zn9Hhi34

Comment: Well, good news is that it's not related to the csrf token. From the code on your question, it seems Comment doesn't understand save() which is weird. Are you sure you're extending Model for Comment?

Comment: Lol, beat me to comment. The new error is easier to solve, check if data is being posted in the request.

Comment: comment_content is definitely showing up in the form data with what I type in.  I amended my controller to have the proper name for the input request as well.  It was content_submission instead of comment_content.  I fixed that but now it still is throwing a cannot be null error.  Will keep researching.